# What is the evidence that Thomas Aquinas was assassinated?

Tags: history, thomas-aquinas, medieval-church, murder

Reading the Wikipedia article on [Thomas Aquinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas), I stumbled on something rather peculiar.  Apparently he fell ill and died at the age of 49 on his way to the [Second Council of Lyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Council_of_Lyon), where he had been summoned by the pope to participate in an effort to reunite the Western and Eastern churches.

Maybe I'm a bit jaded, but it seemed fishy to me that a preeminent scholar "just so happened" to die on his way to such an important event.  I was thus pleased to note that the great [Dante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri) had similar misgivings: he wrote in the [*Divine Comedy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy) that:

> Charles came to Italy, and for amends / A victim made of Conradin, and then
>   / Thrust Thomas back to heaven, for amends. ([*Purgatorio*, 20.67–69](http://www.divinecomedy.org/divine_comedy.php3?display?Enface?Purgatorio?20???151?1???0??1?1))

"Charles" here is apparently [Charles I of Naples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_Naples).  Wikipedia cites a historian who disputes Dante's speculations, but I'm not giving up so easily.

What is the evidence, if any, that Aquinas was assassinated?

Answer (score 2):

A recent biographer of St. Thomas, Jean-Pierre Torrell, says in [*Saint Thomas Aquinas. Volume I, The Person and His Work*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1KUS-cBJmqoC&lpg=PP1&ots=rjoDej8CB2&dq=torell%20aquinas&pg=PA294#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Washington, D.C.: Catholic University of America Press, 2005), [p. 294](https://books.google.com/books?id=1KUS-cBJmqoC&lpg=PP1&ots=rjoDej8CB2&dq=torell%20aquinas&pg=PA294#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The rumor must have circulated rather widely; the chronicler Giovanni Villani and Dante Alighieri himself echo it. It seems that all the historians are in agreement today in discarding this rumor as without serious foundation.

Comment: +1.  Ideally I'd like to understand what the "foundation" is, serious or not, but this is still helpful.

Comment: @Nathaniel See footnote 122 on p. 294.